# How do I mount multiple wasm components to a page?

Tags: html, rust, webassembly, yew

I have a flask project I am working on. I would like to be able to start replacing some components with wasm.

I was able to get the yew component to mount to a specific `<div>`, But I'd like to be able to do that, as well as leverage some of the GUI libaries of Rust.

I was able to make some examples in the iced library work as WASM, but that was as standalone. I havent quite wrapped my head around how to wrap them in a `<div>` and use multiple wasm/rust/yew components on a page.

A very simple example to give you an idea of implementation is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head> 
    <script type="module">
    import init from "./static/js/wasm.js";
    init();
    </script>
    <style>
    #yewapp{}
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <title>Flask+Rust</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
  </head>
  <body>  
    <div>  
      {{ message }}
    </div>
    <div id ="yewapp"></div>
    {{ message }} again
  </body>
</html>
```

This works (yew app is just hello world right now).
I like the `.mount(div)` functionality in yew, but if there is another way to do this I'm open to it.